# How do I concatenate variables that contain path names in a bash script?

Tags: bash

I have the following script that attempts to copy files from a source that has multiple folders, each folder containing several files to a destination folder where all the files should be dumped and rename the files to contain the name of the folder they originated from:

This is done on windows.

```
#!/bin/bash
source_path="c:/Data/Raw/threeObj_test/copy_us"
target_path="c:/Users/installer/Desktop/Val/tmp/"

echo "Coping data from " $source_path " to " $target_path

for curr_dir in $source_path/*/
do 
    curr_subject= basename "$curr_dir"
    curr_source_dir=$curr_dir"Media Files"
    for file in "$curr_source_dir"/*
    do
        file_name= basename "$file"
        new_copy_name="${target_path}${curr_subject}${file_name}"
        echo "$new_copy_name"
        cp "$file" "$new_copy_name"
    done
done
echo "Done copying files"
```

When i run this code the files are actually being copied BUT not renamed as i expect.
The "new_copy_name" appears not to concatenate the other variables...

Tried concatenating also with:
new_copy_name="$target_path$curr_subject$file_name"
but doesn't  help...

What am I missing here in my understanding of how this works?

Comment: Didn't you get an error message from `curr_subject= basename "$curr_dir"` and from `file_name= basename "$file"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign the result of basename like that. I think you would have more insight into at what point it's going wrong if you added a lot more echos.

basename outputs to `stdout` and so to capture that you need to use command substitution:

```bash
curr_subject=$(basename "$curr_dir")
```

Command substitution allows the (standard) output of a command to replace the command itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try pasting your script into https://www.shellcheck.net/ for suggestions.

Sometimes problems like this specific one might be unclear; to see what is happening in your script as it runs, enable debugging mode with `set -x` and read through the output carefully. You can learn a lot just by seeing what each line is actually doing.

[scrhartley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77105593/8656552) is absolutely right. It might be a little confusing though; ;let's take a look at a simplified example and see what's actually happening.

```
$: set -x; x= basename $PWD; set +x # debug on; try to assign; debug off
+ x=
+ basename /tmp
tmp
+ set +x
```

As you can see from the lines preceded by a plus sign in the output (those are the debug logging), the command `x= basename $PWD` is not assigning `tmp` to `x`. It is assigning *nothing*, then running the `basename` command as a separate action.

This is actually what you asked for. `x=` is followed by a tokenizing space, making this assignment an inline temporary prefix assignment scoped only to the execution of the following command. The key there is that you can't put whitespace around the `=` of an assignment.

Let's try it without that space -

```
$: set -x; x=basename $PWD; set +x
+ x=basename
+ /tmp
bash: /tmp: Is a directory
+ set +x
```

Note it successfully assigns the bare string `basename` to the variable `x`, but still as a temporary, ephemeral assignment scoped to the command it precedes - which is just `$PWD`, the Present Working Directory value, my `/tmp` directory. You can't really run the directory as a command, so it throws an error message. This still isn't what you want.

It does not try to run `basename` as a command in this example, because there was no space tokenizing it as separate from the assignment, and so it parsed the context as a value, a string to assign.

What you want (again, as [scrhartley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77105593/8656552) demonstrated already) is to run the `basename` command and catch the output. There are lots of ways to do that, such as the `curr_subject=$(basename "$curr_dir")` he suggested. The `$(...)` structure runs the command inside and effectively replaces itself with the output, so that the assignment gets what is generated. Using that in my example above:

```
$: set -x; x=$(basename $PWD); set +x
++ basename /tmp
+ x=tmp
+ set +x
```

Note the *double* plus signs, indicating a subcommand run by the command, then the assignment showing the return from the command as what is used to assign the value to the variable.

You can also get much the same result using [Bash parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
$: set -x; x=${PWD##*/}; set +x
+ x=tmp
+ set +x
```

Note this doesn't require a subshell.

Another comment - make sure to read up on [quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) rules. It's generally a good habit to always quote your variables unless there's some specific reason not to do so. I notice this line in your script:

```
echo "Coping data from " $source_path " to " $target_path
```

I find it odd that you went to extra effort to quote plain text, but *exclude* the variables from the quotes.
Let's take a minute to compare some examples.

```
$: echo "Copying data from " $source_path " to " $target_path # embeds extra spaces
Copying data from  c:/Data/Raw/threeObj_test/copy_us  to  c:/Users/installer/Desktop/Val/tmp/

$: echo "Copying data from $source_path to $target_path" # clean
Copying data from c:/Data/Raw/threeObj_test/copy_us to c:/Users/installer/Desktop/Val/tmp/

$: echo "Copying data from ${source_path} to ${target_path}" # same
Copying data from c:/Data/Raw/threeObj_test/copy_us to c:/Users/installer/Desktop/Val/tmp/

$: echo Copying data from $source_path to $target_path # not good habit, but works for this example
Copying data from c:/Data/Raw/threeObj_test/copy_us to c:/Users/installer/Desktop/Val/tmp/

$: echo Copying   data   from   "$source_path to   $target_path" # quoted extra spaces preserved; unquoted were not
Copying data from c:/Data/Raw/threeObj_test/copy_us to   c:/Users/installer/Desktop/Val/tmp/

$: echo "Copying data from '$source_path' to '$target_path'" # clearer; the double quotes protect the vards from the singles
Copying data from 'c:/Data/Raw/threeObj_test/copy_us' to 'c:/Users/installer/Desktop/Val/tmp/'

$: echo Copying data from '$source_path' to '$target_path' # doesn't work! Singles prevent expansion
Copying data from $source_path to $target_path
```

This sort of thing really matters most when you have characters that mean something to the parser, like spaces, being used in things like variable values and filenames.

```
$: set -x; file="has space"; touch $file "$file"; ls -l $file "$file"; set +x
+ file='has space'
+ touch has space 'has space'
+ ls -l has space 'has space'
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep 14 10:29  has
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep 14 10:29 'has space'
-rw-r--r-- 1 paul 1049089 0 Sep 14 10:29  space
+ set +x

$: set -x; rm $file; ls -l $file "$file"; set +x
+ rm has space
+ ls -l has space 'has space'
ls: cannot access 'has': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'space': No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 P2759474 1049089 0 Sep 14 10:32 'has space'
+ set +x
```

Note the `touch $file "$file"`; with no quotes passed `has` and `space` as separate arguments, which created them as separate files; with quotes included the embedded space in the filename. The `rm $file` with no quotes removed `has` and `space` but not `'has space'`. Handling of that embedded space in the filename can be critical.